# How to call JS function on click of JSF button and block page reload/navigation?

Tags: jsf, button, primefaces, onclick

What is the preferred way to create a button with JSF to call JS function ?

Actually I use :

```
<p:button onclick="myJSFunction();" href="#"/>
```

but my urls are suffixed with the anchor symbol (`#`).

Is there another recommended way to create button which will not reload/navigate to URL but call JS function please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because it's actually navigating to `#`. You need to block the button from performing its default action, which is navigating to the current view, or to the URL as specified in `href` or `outcome`. You can achieve this by adding `return false;` to the end of `onclick`.

```
<p:button onclick="myJSFunction(); return false;" />
```

Or, if `myJSFunction()` actually returns a `boolean` which should determine if the button should continue its default action, then delegate to it:

```
<p:button onclick="return myJSFunction();" />
```

The `<h:button>` works exactly the same way, it's only in standard look'n'feel.

An alternative is to use `<p:commandButton type="button">`, which generates a real `<input type="button">` without any navigation. This way you don't need to return false from `onclick`.

```
<p:commandButton type="button" onclick="myJSFunction()" />
```

This however requires a `<h:form>` (although placing it outside any form doesn't break any functionality). The same applies to `<h:commandButton>`.

Comment: mea culpa, you already told me the `return false;` method in another post...and I forgot it ! As always, it's work like a charm, thank you !