# Controlling the onClick or onSucess events from bean (primefaces)?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, dom-events

I need to show *`in another tab`* the generate Report with bean method (`bean.generateReporte())`. And show a message when the Report is not possible to be generated (not data is found according to criteria).

**my first code in the .xhtml was**:

```
<p:commandButton id="printDeliveryList" label="Generate Delivery List" styleClass="btn-success"
     style="float:left" icon="fa fa-print" 
     action="#{bean.generateReporte()}"
     onclick="this.form.target = '_blank'"
     ajax="false"
 />
```

I was reading this question [How to prevent commandButton from executing action when onclick method return false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36087914/811293) and this question [How to call JS function on click of JSF button and block page reload/navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14204612/811293)
and this post https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2011/09/14/primefaces-client-side-ajax-events/
And this documentation 
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml

I was thinking in `onsuccess` event.

Here my code later....

In the **`bean`** side I have:

```
public void generateReporte() {
    // blabla
    if (success) {
        addGeneratedToCallback(true);
    } else {
        addGeneratedToCallback(false);
    }
}

private void addGeneratedToCallback(boolean value) {
    PrimeFaces.current().ajax().addCallbackParam("generated", value);
}
```

In the **`.xhtml`** side

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleComplete(xhr, status, args) {
        if (args.validationFailed) {
            PrimeFaces.debug("Validation Failed");
        } else {
            if (args.generated) {
                // open a new tab in the browser
                //window.open(this.form.target = '_blank');
                form.target = '_blank';
            } else {
                // show message
            }
        }
    }
</script>


<p:commandButton id="printListaEntrega" label="Generar Lista de Entrega" styleClass="btn-success"
                 style="float:left" icon="fa fa-print" 
                 action="#{bean.generateReporte()}"
                 ajax="false"
                 oncomplete="handleComplete(xhr, status, args)"
                 />
```

**The Result of my code**

With `ajax="false"` I got this when the generation of Report is not possible.
[image]

When I remove `ajax="false"` from the `p:commandButton` and the report is generated I got. (Not open the new tab in browser And Can't download the report)
[image]

**Is it possible to set contitional `ajax="bean.someMethodOrProperty"`?**

Comment: I fail ro see what you are actually asking, or rather, why you want to solve aomethibg this way?

Comment: @Kukeltje sorry yesterday I need to leave the office, but I edited my question.

Comment: I feel this is a http://xyproblem.info Can you state what you want to achieve functional wise?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37519295/jsf-file-download-exception-handling-how-to-prevent-view-rerendering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF file download exception handling (how to prevent view rerendering)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37519295/jsf-file-download-exception-handling-how-to-prevent-view-rerendering)

Comment: This is better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591795/conditionally-provide-either-file-download-or-show-export-validation-error-messa

Comment: You are very welcome. Thank you for the appreciation. Great incentive to help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In the `.xhtml`

```
<p:commandButton id="printDeliveryList" label="Generate Delivery List" styleClass="btn-success"
                 style="float:left" icon="fa fa-print" 
                 action="#{bean.generateReport()}"
                 oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) {PF('download').jq.click();PF('openNewTab').jq.click() }"
                 />
<p:commandButton widgetVar="download" styleClass="ui-helper-hidden" 
                 action="#{bean.downloadFile()}" ajax="false" />
<p:commandButton widgetVar="openNewTab" styleClass="ui-helper-hidden" 
                 action="#{bean.openInNewTab()}" 
                 onclick="this.form.target = '_blank'" ajax="false" />
```

in the bean

```
public void generateReport() {
    // blabla
    if (success) {
        bytesToBeDownload = getBytesOfReport();
        nameOfFile = getNameOfReport() + ".pdf";
    } else {
        Faces.validationFailed();
    }
}


public void downloadFile() {
    try {
        // byte[] bytesToBeDownload = ....
        org.omnifaces.util.Faces.sendFile(bytesToBeDownload, nameOfFile, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Exception handling
    }
}


public void openInNewTab() {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = bytesToBeDownload;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bytes.length);
        baos.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        buildResponse(baos, "application/pdf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Exception handling
    }
}


private static void buildResponse(ByteArrayOutputStream out, String contentType) {

    ByteArrayInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {

        input = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
        int bufferSize = out.toByteArray().length;

        FacesUtils.getHttpServletResponse().reset();
        FacesUtils.getHttpServletResponse().setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
        FacesUtils.getHttpServletResponse().setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(bufferSize));
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(FacesUtils.getHttpServletResponse().getOutputStream(), bufferSize);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        output.flush();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Exception handling
    } finally {
        try {
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Exception handling
        }
    }
    FacesUtils.getFacesContext().responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: Great you solved it. But when you answer (effectively not really needed since the question seems to be a full duplicate) adding a little text as an explanation what happens where and why would be very much appreciated by others. Adding explicit references to the posts you used (giving credits to the others and also upvoting the other Q/A's) is a good thing to do as well.!

Comment: @Kukeltje Thank you. I need to do one of two (erase the question or edit the question/answer). I'm really ashamed. But What is your recommendation about of this? To Edit it, in order to related the answer based on (or from of), I think is needed.